# Erro no vagrant up windows 10

Tags: laravel, vagrant, homestead

Estou usando o homestead e o vagrant para criar uma Máquina virtual e rodar meus projetos web. Entretanto, não consigo entrar nos meus hosts *(ex: meusite.dev)*, todos já estão devidamente configurados no **homestead.yaml** e no arquivo **hosts** do windows, entretanto, sempre que aplico o comando **vagrant up**, no final do comando recebo a seguinte mensagem de erro:

```
==> homestead-7:
==> homestead-7:   [Composer\Downloader\TransportException]                                               
==> homestead-7:   The "https://getcomposer.org/versions" file could not be downloaded: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known
==> homestead-7:   failed to open stream: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known
==> homestead-7:                                                                                          
==> homestead-7:
==> homestead-7: self-update [-r|--rollback] [--clean-backups] [--no-progress] [--update-keys] [--stable] [--preview] [--snapshot] [--] [<version>]
The SSH command responded with a non-zero exit status. Vagrant
assumes that this means the command failed. The output for this command
should be in the log above. Please read the output to determine what
went wrong.
```

Tanto o **bash, como o vagrant, como o composer** já estão devidamente instalados e atualizados. O que poderia ser esse erro?

Answer (score 2):

Olá,

O problema provavelmente é a configuração do servidor de DNS no sistema operacional dentro do seu box do vagrant. Para resolver, execute os seguintes comandos:

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
dns-search google.com
dns-nameservers dnsserverip
```

E reinicie o serviço de rede:

```
sudo service network restart
```

Mais detalhes podem ser vistos [nesta página](https://coderwall.com/p/ngobsw/handling-php-s-getaddrinfo-failed-errors-in-a-linux-server-when-using-vagrant) onde achei o problema resolvido (em inglês).

Tente o procedimento e me diga se funcionou,

Abraço.

Comment: Ideoliveira, como aplico esses comandos via terminal? dentro de alguma pasta em específico?

Comment: só logar via SSH e digitar um comando por vez

Comment: foi o que tentei agora... mas quando digito o comando aparece: "-bash: auto: command not found"

Comment: veja se o comando "vagrant login" funciona https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/cli/login.html

Comment: fora do "vagrant ssh" funciona, dentro do ssh não funciona e apresenta o mesmo erro.

Comment: eu estou usando linux - ubuntu 16.4 LTS. Já descobri a questão, eles são escritos dentro de:  sudo vi /etc/network/interface e não diretamente no terminal.

Comment: @ideoliveira, só não estou conseguindo executar o último comando: // vagrant@homestead:~$ sudo service network restart
Failed to restart network.service: Unit network.service not found.

Comment: sim, estou conectado!

Comment: tente esse: sudo ifdown eth0 && sudo ifup eth0

Comment: dei o comando, mas apareceu: "Unknown interface eth0"

Answer (score 1):

O erro consiste em um **conflito DNS**, mesmo que se crie um **proxy, atualize servernames** ou tente recursos forçados para configuração da conexão, a única alternativa que libera o comando é atualizando o windows usando o recurso do windows update ou utilizando um cd de instalação.

A Microsoft não se pronunciou sobre o assunto, mas atualizar **o windows com Packs de correção gera um refresh da **DNSzone e reconfigura os protocolos de internet para trabalhar com a Virtual Machine.**, permitindo assim, o update do composer via ssh e a remoção do erro "php_network_getaddresses"